# is it possible to pass json format in browser's url address bar? (GET method)

Tags: json, web-services, http

want to test my url service in browser but need to pass json format data.

I tried the below but no success:
http://locahost:8042/service/getinfo?body={"name":"H&M"}

or any tool that can be use to pass json formatted test data?

**UPDATES1**
I mean is to pass the json formatted data manually in browser's url address bar. Like as my example above. This is for quick testing only not for implementation.

Comment: You're probably better off using a REST testing tool to quickly re-run your tests. I know PostMan is popular but I usually use the one built into my IDE (PhpStorm).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you certainly can pass JSON in a URL Querystring.  You just have to URLencode the JSON string first.  As @dmn said, the data is probably better passed via POST because of GET's size restrictions.

Comment: I just wanted to literally type the json data to browser's url address bar. Would you provide some example?

Comment: Well, you could paste your JSON code into http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and copy the encoded JSON into your URL querystring.  Just be sure to unencode the string after you send it to your script.  All scripting languages have a version of an URLunencode function.

Comment: URLEncoding works just fine. I use [Rishida](http://people.w3.org/rishida/tools/conversion/) for my conversion needs.

Comment: @JonathanWilson There is no size restriction for GET ;)

Answer (score 1):

The { and } characters are considered unsafe for unencoded use in a URL.

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably putting it in the GET won't be a good idea, since url parameters have a limit of 256 characters. It would be better if you use POST and put the JSON in the body and after that you can parse it using Jackson for example or gson ... and get the result as an object.

Comment: Yes I am considering the size. That's why I just wanted to try it. Would you give some example?

Comment: This is simply not true...at least not in 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Add Extension to chrome web-browser called 'Advance rest Client' and change contain header to application/json and make json object and post in pay load then hit send bottom it works for json object

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqIbr.png)
[image]

This is how I am doing in my web service, I am passing a json and within the service I manage it.

Comment: Please copy-paste your code here, don't use images as they are far less readable and can expire :)

Comment: Of course, I leave you the code for what you consider

Answer (score -1):

Just do a URL query like this:

```
http://locahost:8042/service/getinfo?name=h%26m
```

`%26` is the encoding of `&`